# Extracting Production Data using Python

Tags: python, parsing, response, payload

I am fairly new to Python and I'm trying to extract production data from the Alabama state website (https://www.gsa.state.al.us/ogb/production). I was wondering if someone could guide me on starting this? This is what I have so far. I was trying to extract production for permit number 8132-C.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36',
 }

payload = '8132-C'
session = requests.Session()

r = requests.get('https://www.gsa.state.al.us/ogb/production', 
params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

Comment: What is your problem actually ?

Comment: Do you want to get the .csv file?

Comment: I'm trying to parse the data from the .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `r.url` , you should `r.text` to see the data.

```
import requests

payload = '8132-C'
session = requests.Session()
r = requests.get('https://www.gsa.state.al.us/ogb/production', params=payload)
print(r.text)
```